# Javascript Library for charts to integrate WinJS

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am asking about some JavaScript library or API that I can integrate it in my winjs/HTML Windows store application.
I would like to connect it with  my data to render some awesome charts or pies etc.
If someone have any library in mind it will be helpful for me.

Comment: have you tried using any js chart library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can use any of the diverse Javascript graphing libraries out there. It will depend on what you want to achieve but here's a couple of libraries I found to be of very high quality:

- http://g.raphaeljs.com/ (very straightforward)
- http://d3js.org/ (more power, more complexity)
- http://www.flotcharts.org/ (nice plugin system)

In case charting is an important part of your app, this commercial library may be for you http://www.highcharts.com/

I also found this [very extensive list](http://techslides.com/50-javascript-charting-and-graphics-libraries/) which has even more charting libraries on it but didn't sift through it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution built specifically for Windows 8 HTML and WinJS, then look at the [RacControls for Windows 8](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/overview.aspx). They contain a wide array of charts and graphs, as well as SparkLines (coming in beta in the next couple of days) for very lightweight rendering of your data visualizations.  If you are looking for Cross Platform, [Kendo UI DataViz](http://www.kendoui.com/) has many of the same options.

[Full disclosure, I work for Telerik as the Senior Developer Evangelist for DevTools]